# Errors Message for Validation

Tags: php, kohana

I'm working on authorization system for Kohana. I'm doing it just for education...

This is how looks my controller that checks submitted fields:

```
$validation =
  Validation::factory( $_POST )
    ->rule( 'username', 'not_empty' )
    ->rule( 'username', 'max_length', array( ':value', 32 ) )
    ->rule( 'username', 'alpha_dash', array( ':value', true ) )
    ->rule( 'password', 'not_empty' )
    ->rule( 'password', 'min_length', array( ':value', 6 ) )
    ->rule( 'password', 'max_length', array( ':value', 255 ) )
    ->rule( 'passwordRepeatedly', 'not_empty' )
    ->rule( 'passwordRepeatedly', 'matches', array( ':validation', 'passwordRepeatedly', 'password' ) )
    ->rule( 'email', 'not_empty' )
    ->rule( 'email', 'email' );
```

I'm looking for the way to display different error message for each added rule. My goal is then pass it (one or all (if occurs)) to view and display them there.

Pseudo-code:

```
errorFor( 'username', 'not_empty' ) => 'Username is required! Try again...';
```

How to define different error for each rule? I can't find anything understandable for me in the docs...

Comment: the same way you applying the rules just associate an error string or an array with the rule where you apply the validation throw the error as an exception or return its value

Comment: Can you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
$validation = ...
```

So, first you should check if variables pass validation:

```
if($validation->check()) 
{
  // no errors
}
else
{
    $errors = $validation->errors('user');
}
```

Then you should have **user.php** file in **application/messages**

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

  return array
  (
     'input_name' => array
     (
        'rule' => 'your message',
        'default' => 'default message'
     ),
     'username' => array
     (
        'not_empty' => 'your message',
        'max_length' => 'your message',
        'alpha_dash' => 'your message',
        'default' => 'default message'
     ),

  );

?>
```

To display errors:

```
foreach($errors as $input_field => $message) 
    echo $message;
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation rules make use of **messages** folder in your application directory.

Check this: http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm/examples/validation for full validation example, where the messages file is at the very bottom of the page.

The things to note are the **directory** and the **filename** of the message file.

In KO3.1 (I believe) the Validation throws an exception whenever if fails. If you catch it with `catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)` you can use `$e->errors('some_directory')` to catch error messages, which are then pulled from `messages/some_directory/model_name.php` in the form of array, just like in the example from the link above.